# How to extract equation of line from OpenCV edge detection image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I have an image that I've conducted edge detection on and its highlighted a curve within the image. I want to be able to extract the equation of that curve. I've put a red line on the image to show which equation I want to extract. Im not sure how to begin so any advice would be great!

[image]

Comment: what is the puose of getting the equation of that curve ?

Comment: I need to match it to a known equation to calculate possible errors

Comment: multilayer perceptron models can help you I believe. getting an equation seems will cost  to a higher degree equation cos of many unknown

Comment: Did you draw the red line manually and you need to extract the curve or is the red line already the result which you need to compare to the given equation?

Comment: I put the red line on manually

Comment: As you have the coordinates for every pixel on the line I would go for a [cubic-spline interpolation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/interpolate.html#d-interpolation-interp1d)